# Open URL in IE using Java's Desktop class

Tags: java

The Desktop class opens a URL in the user's default browser when using the open() method. How can a URL be opened in IE even when IE is not the default browser?

Edit: Solutions do not have to use the Desktop class. I was using that as an example.

Comment: you can't, you can only open it in the default browser.

Comment: @liv solutions don't have to use the Desktop class. I know you can open IE by calling exec() also, but it doesn't seem very elegant

Comment: why do you want to open it in another browser?

Comment: you're right -- it's not elegant and it's not portable since different windows version have IE installed in different locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try invoking, in `System.exec()` `iexplore.exe 'http://my.url'`, which is the name of Internet explorer executable.